# Wordpress loop how to get tag slug and be value in query_posts

Tags: post, get, tags, wordpress

What I am trying to do is:

- Among the posts in category 1  every post has a tag
- Now in another post under another category I want to call the posts from category 1 which have the same tag for example `cat=1&tag=1` and `cat=2&tag=1`

Here is the code and it's not working:

```
<?php

            $t = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);

                         query_posts( 'cat=45&tag=' . $t. '' );
                                        // The Loop
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `tag id` in the `query_posts` and the `wp_get_post_tags()` returns the array not the id so the best to achieve the posts by tag you have to pass the tag-id which

```
<?php

     $t = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);

     query_posts( 'cat=45&tag=' . $t[0]->term_id. '' );
                                        // The Loop
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

there can be multiple tags so you have to loop through `$t` to get all the tag ids

Please refer to this manual [**wp_get_post_tags**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_tags)